# How can I regex replace all spaces in matched text with underscore? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have the following:

```
enum class test {
    something1, // this is a comment
    something2, // something else
    something3,
};
```

I want to convert it to:

```
enum class test {
    something1 | this_is_a_comment
    something2 | something_else
    something3,
};
```

so I need to replace the spaces of all the text after // with underscores

I have this so far:

```
/\,.*\/\/\s*(.*)/g
```

This will select the text I want but how to replace the spaces?

I don't really have to use regex so any solution is appreciated!

Comment: Where are the underscores in the result?

Comment: the comments eg this is a comment > this_is_a_comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function in the `replace()` method. That function can perform a nested replacement on that capture group.

```js
let str = `enum class test{
    something1, // this is a comment
    something2, // something else
    something3,
};`;

let new_str = str.replace(/\,.*\/\/\s*(.*)/g, (match0, match1) => ' | ' + match1.replace(/ /g, '_'));
console.log(new_str);
```

.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as a second argument of replace. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

It will be called with the full match then each of the groups in order. That means you can resolve your problem like this:

`str.replace(/\,.*\/\/\s*(.*)/g, (match, group1) => " | " + group1.replace(/\s/g, "_"))`